# How to access Metadata from audio files in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am working on the simulation of `MusicPlayer` in Qt using QML,
Here is my code to access the metadata from the `.mp3` file

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Audio {
        id:audio1
        source:"/music/2.mp3"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: { console.log(audio1.metaData.title) }
}
```

but the output is `undefined` for `metaData.title`.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `console.log(audio1.metaData.title)` media is not loaded yet.
You need to check `status` property.

**Example:**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Audio {   
        id:audio1
        source:"/music/2.mp3"

        onStatusChanged: {
            if(status == MediaPlayer.Loaded) {
                console.log(audio1.metaData.author)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If media is file, status will never become Loaded, it will be Buffered instead.